# Add data to an existing Place? Or add new Place with same address?

Tags: google-places-api

I am looking into using Google Places to store a list of locations that sell a certain product. Turns out that most of the stores that sell it are already in Places.

Looking at the Places docs, it seems that I can add a new store, but how do I add a feild to an existing Place? Is this even possible?

Or, what happens if i add a new place at the same address as an existing Place?

Answer (score 0):

I am concerned that your use case does not meet the Google Places Terms of service, specifically section `10.1.3 (b) No Pre-Fetching, Caching, or Storage of Content`:

> https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_1_3

I would suggest changing your application to only retrieve the required locations when needed instead of storing them.

You can indeed add a new Place using the Google Places API, however it is not possible to add new fields to new or existing place.

Adding a new place, even if at the same location as another place will follow the moderation process described in the documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceReports

If you add the same place at the same location as an existing place, it probably wont pass moderation to be visible to all applications using the Places API, but it will always be visible to your application until deleted.